# How do i use an if else statement for inner join ON query?

Tags: sql, join

TableC

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |    id_branch     |   id_supplier    | qty              | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         9        |                  | 2                |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |                  |         20       | 3                |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

This is  sample table where i want to get my result from this table.

I have a query

```
// P is product table
      LEFT JOIN tableC  AS C ON C.id_supplier = P.id_supplier AND C.id_branch = P.id_branch
```

How can i left join both id_branch and id_supplier to display qty?

Currently it will only show the product from id_branch even select the product from id_supplier.

If i am changing the left join to

```
// P is product table
      LEFT JOIN tableC  AS C ON C.id_supplier = P.id_supplier OR C.id_branch = P.id_branch
```

When choose to display all product then it will show all from id_supplier, and it will display the item from id_branch if selected item is from id_branch.

How can i properly left join both id_branch and id_supplier and display the information about them?

Comment: Whole query, more sample data and its expected result would perhaps make the problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your query, it sounds like you should be left joining to `tableC` twice:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    -- more fields?
    COALESCE(c1.field1, 'NA') AS field1,
    COALESCE(c2.field2, 'NA') AS field2
LEFT JOIN tableC c1
    ON c1.id_supplier = P.id_supplier
LEFT JOIN tableC c2
    ON c2.id_branch = P.id_branch
```

Comment: Yes, i am going to left joining my tableC twice. From my query, i am selecting something like "Select c.id,c.qty from tableC as c left join...", from my last statement i only left join one time, and the result will only show id_supplier. If left joining tableC twice, is that possible to use e.g. c.qty instead of creating new field?

Comment: @Zidance You still haven't showed us your full query or any data.  Now would be a good time to do that.